# Tengo un problema al ejecutar openai gym en vscode

Tags: python, vscode, inteligencia-artificial

Descargue OpenAI gym desde la consola, no dio ningun error, pero cuando ejecuto el archivo no pasa nada. Asi que no se que hacer, o que me recomiendan.
La idea es que se abra una ventana con un pequeño juego de una montaña rusa controlada por la IA, pero no se abre la ventana. Algo parecido al modulo Turtle de python.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El código va como texto en las preguntas. Cómo instalaste el módulo en python? Seguiste las [instrucciones](https://github.com/openai/gym)? Seguro que estás corriendo esto en la versión de python donde lo instalaste? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).